# Object doesn't support property or method 'i18n' when trying to display datatable buttons in MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to get the jquery datatable export buttons to display on an cshtml view in my MVC application.
The error is

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'i18n'  Unhandled exception at line 13, column 363 in
>   http://localhost:52104/Scripts/buttons.html5.min.js which points to
>   the buttons.html5.min.js script text:function(a){return
>   a.i18n("buttons.excel","Excel")}

I created a proof of concept view just to see if the buttons would show up and work.  The scripts are included in the BundleConfig.cs file

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/misc_scripts").Include(
"~/Scripts/autosize.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
"~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
"~/Scripts/dataTables.responsive.min.js",
"~/Scripts/dataTables.buttons.min.js",
"~/Scripts/buttons.html5.min.js",
"~/Scripts/buttons.print.min.js",
"~/Scripts/jszip.min.js",
"~/Scripts/pdfmake.min.js",
"~/Scripts/vfs_fonts.js",
"~/Scripts/select2.min.js",
"~/Scripts/App/Shared.js"

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['excelHtml5']
         });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not 100% sure this will fix it, but I think your script files are in the wrong order, which could affect the dependencies. Try this order: autosize, jszip, pdfmake, vfs_fonts, then leave everything else in the same order it was in but after vfs_fonts.

Comment: Hi Chris,  Tried changing the order as you suggested but it is still throwing the same error in buttons.html5.min.js

Comment: I wasn't sure it would, just something to try. At least you've narrowed down your list of potential causes :/

Comment: I just published the solution to IIS, the buttons are showing up.  When I run the view locally in VS2013 the error gets thrown